# Coding style: checking user input is messy. Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: java, validation, coding-style

Whenever I check user input it always gets really messy. An example of this might be address input. You could have the following:

13B Main Street
13 B Main Street
13b, Main Street
13 B, Main Street

If I were coding this, it would end up like

```
String number,letter,street; //To be filled with "13","B","Main Street"
String address = getUserInput();
String[] tokens = address.split(" ");

if(tokens[0].isNumeric() == false){
    //It could be 13B rather than 13
    String number = "";
    for(Character c: tokens[0].toCharArray()){
        if(c.isDigit() == false){
            //We could have found the apartment letter
            if(number.isEmpty()){
                //The address is invalid, throw error.
            } else {
                //Make sure it was a letter
                if(c.isLetter()){
                    letter = c;
                } else {
                    //throw error
                }
            }
        } else {
            number += c;
        }
    }
} else {
    //...continue all other possibilities
}
```

Note that the above code is something I threw together quickly - some of the methods don't exist and it won't compile.

My point is that it just looks *messy*. So many ifs inside ifs. When I look at it I see something very unelegant. If I were to actually code to entire thing, capable of taking addresses in those 4 formats, it would be scores and scores of lines of code.

Is there a trick I'm missing here? Is there a way to make it any less ugly?

Comment: Unless you can come up with a neat regular expression, parsing code is going to be messy. Complicated parser code, like for programming languages, is usually generated by some external utility so as to spare a human from messing around with it. You seem to be on the right track for this specialized application.

Comment: The only thing that should be checked in an address is that it doesn't contain characters that could lead to a SQL injection. The regex for your requirements wouldn't be too much complicated, but you're going to create a very hard to fill address input field. And, did you think what happens with people that lives in the 2nd floor of that address? Or people living in places where there's no house number, like some country places? And people living in different countries?

Comment: FYI `if(c.isDigit() == false)` can be simply written as `if (!c.isDigit())`

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are commonly used for input validation, and will be germane to your question. An excellent tutorial can be found here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Checking every possible permutation is nearly impossible. You're best best is to make sure that it contains only numbers or letters, possibly using a `regex`. Reason being that there are so many  different types of addresses, you can't possibly account for the all. However, you do know that an addresses street has only letters and numbers (sometimes a `-` or hyphen), but I think you get the point. You can check to make sure that the address only contains valid characters, but anything beyond that is going to be messy & time consuming.

By using a regex, you can check to make sure the address only contains valid characters in 1 or 2 lines of code, which is much cleaner.

Like:

```
String address = getUserInput();
if(address.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9]*"))
{
  //perform actions for accurate address
}
else
{
  //do other action for invalid address
}
```

Comment: Now the regular expression doesn't make sense.

Comment: How so? If the address does not match letters/numbers...?

Comment: The regex will only match a string with the length of 1, if it's a non digit, or non letter. It won't match every string longer than 1.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `if` for valid and `else` for invalid input, or the other way around?

Comment: If I live on `Préfontaine Street` I guess I'm out of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You will always need to check if a string is [empty](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) (i.e. Checks if a CharSequence is empty ("") or null)  or [blank](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) (i.e Checks if a CharSequence is whitespace, empty ("") or null) and many other stuff.

There are even convenience methods such is isNotBlank and isNotEmpty that relieves you from negating your logical conditions.

[Apache Commons StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) can do this easily for you.